# My Model creates an extra key for the database why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

**Note:** Technoligies in use are ASP.Net MVC 3, Entity, SQL Server Management Studio

### Problem?

It seems that when I run, the context as: `public class DatabaseInit : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<LocationAppContext>`

That it creates the database, but my service assignments table has an extra foreign key called
`ServiceAssignment_Service` when it shouldn't.

My service assignment model is as such:

```
namespace LocationApp.Models
{
    public class ServiceAssignment
    { 
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int locationID { get; set; }
        public int ServiceID { get; set; }

        public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
        public virtual ServiceAssignment Service { get; set;}
    }

}
```

and the service model is as such:

```
namespace LocationApp.Models
{
    public class Service
    {
        public Service()
        {
            this.ServiceAssignments = new HashSet<ServiceAssignment>();
        }

        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public bool active { get; set; }
        public string icon { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ServiceAssignment> ServiceAssignments { get; set; }
    }
}
```

with that said, the relation ship is simple:

service assignments have many location id's and service id's.

why is this extra foriegn key being generated? the curent keys, that should e there is:

- **PK**: Main PK for the table
- **FK 1**: Location_ServiceAssignment
- **FK 2**: Service_ServiceAssignment

Those are their, how ever this third one is baffling....

The second part is: If a location of id 2 has a service id of 2,3,6,7 How do I get all service id's returned, such that I can pass the object to a service query to get all information on the service based on the ID?

### Update:

Context Class:

```
namespace LocationApp.DAL
{
    public class LocationAppContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Content> Contents { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Location> Locations { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ServiceAssignment> ServiceAssignments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Service> Services { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Location>().HasMany(sa => sa.ServiceAssignments);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Service>().HasMany(sa => sa.ServiceAssignments);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your relation betweeen service and location is many to many ?

Comment: I remember I had some problem like this, the problem was that I wrote the mappings wrong, it happens when the many to many or one to many are not mapped correctly, or the exact foreign keys are not wrote, show us the mappings you wrote for these classes.

Comment: @Shyju Locations can have many services as a service can have many locations.

Also Please see updated OP for the mappings.

Comment: and if you are new to EF, I'd recommend to first create the database by SQL server management tools and then generate the classes and mappings by this free tool : "Entity Framework Power Tools", to see how it correctly is done. just install it, write click on your project and you see a new option Entity framework, it connects to DB and generate classes and mapping and everything you need.: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d

Comment: @TheWebs: Why are you having `ServiceAssignments `. Is that only for having the Many-Many relation between the tables ?

Comment: @Shyju I dont get a say in the tables, I create what I am told. as for ePezhman, again, I don't get to choose how we create things, I am told to create it one way, I am just here to see if the fix can be a qucik one. I can't get ahold of any devs in office so stack it is.

Comment: @ePezhman When doing that, I tend to get the same resualts in terms of set up in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to tell EF that `Service.ServiceAssignments` is the inverse navigation property of `ServiceAssignment.Service` and that `Location.ServiceAssignments` is the inverse of `ServiceAssignment.Location`. Right now with your mapping you only specify that `Location` or `Service` has many `ServiceAssignments`. EF will consider the navigation properties in `ServiceAssignment` as the ends of separate relationships.

Try instead the mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Location>()
    .HasMany(l => l.ServiceAssignments)
    .WithRequired(sa => sa.Location)
    .HasForeignKey(sa => sa.LocationID);

modelBuilder.Entity<Service>()
    .HasMany(s => s.ServiceAssignments)
    .WithRequired(sa => sa.Service)
    .HasForeignKey(sa => sa.ServiceID);
```

You can probably remove this mapping altogether as an alternative because EF should detect the right relationships by convention.

So, use either no mapping (=mapping by convention) or the full mapping (=specifying *both* ends of the relationships). Just the 50%-mapping you have used is likely the problem.